# How do I integrate a function defined piece-wise?

Tags: calculus, integration

> Consider the  function
>
> $f(x)=  \begin{cases} 1 ,\ 0\le x\le  1, \\ 0 ,\ 1< x \le 2 \end {cases}$
>
> what is  $g(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt $ on  $[0,2] ?$

My attempt :  $g(x) =\begin{cases} 1 \int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt,\ 0\le x\le  1, \\ 0\int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt ,\ 1< x \le 2 \end {cases}=\begin{cases} x ,\ 0\le x\le  1, \\ 0 ,\ 1< x \le 2 \end {cases}$

Is its  True  ?

Comment: No.  An integral from $0$ to $x$ with $x>1$ is an integral from $0$ to $1$ plus an integral from $1$ to $x$.

Comment: thanks u @NicNic8

Comment: @jasmine I was wrong.  GEdgar is correct.

Comment: yes GEdgar has the right answer here.

$g(x) = x*1_{x \in [0,1]}+1_{x \in [1,2]}$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst  How  $1 _{ x \in [1,2]} ?$ come

Comment: because whenever $x\in[1,2]$, you get the full integral from 0 to 1 of 1, and also the integral from 1 to 2 of f(t), which is just adding zero.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst can  u eloborate in  answer  box    im not  getting

Comment: $g(x) =\begin{cases} \int_{0}^{x} 1dt,\ 0\le x\le  1, \\ \int_{0}^{1} 1dt+\int_{1}^{x}0dt ,\ 1< x \le 2 \end {cases}=\begin{cases} x ,\ 0\le x\le  1, \\ 0 ,\ 1< x \le 2 \end {cases}$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst It should be $g(x) = 1$ for $1<x\leqslant 2$ (since we are also integrating over $(0,1)$.

Comment: yeah that is a typo oops

Comment: That typo is the only reason I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $0\leq x \leq 1$ we get 
$$\int_0^xf(x)\,dx = \int_0^x1\,dx = x.$$
For $1<x\leq 2$ we get 
$$\int_0^xf(x)\,dx = \int_0^11\,dx + \int_1^x0\,dx = 1 + 0 = 1.$$
By consequence:
$$g(x) = \begin{cases}
x & 0\leq x \leq 1 \\
1 & 1 < x \leq 2
\end{cases}
$$